# Сортировка списка фамилий

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int alphabeth(string name, string character, int i) {
    character = name[i];
    int ord;
    if (character == "a") ord = 0;
    else if (character == "b") ord = 1;
    else if (character == "c") ord = 2;
    else if (character == "d") ord = 3;
    else if (character == "e") ord = 4;
    else if (character == "f") ord = 5;

    return ord;
}

int main() {

    int n;
    cout << "List size: ";
    cin >> n;
    vector <string> a(n);


    for (int i = 0; i != n; i++) {
        int z = 0;


        string FIO;
        cin >> FIO;
        string first;

        a[alphabeth(FIO, first, z)] = FIO;
    }

    cout << "Sorted list: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i != n; i++) {

    cout << a[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

Это мой код по сортировке фамилий,
Входят фамилии, пробегаются по функции Алфавит, и потом им присваивается соответствующее значение в массиве.

Ошибок не выдаёт, но мой Dev-C++ и cpp.sh останавливают работу когда я начинаю вводить фамилии.

Как заставить его работать без вылета?

Comment: Я вставил return 0; Он заработал один раз. Потом начал вылетать, когда нужно было выводить сортированный список.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сортировки есть функция `sort`. Чтобы она работала, нужно подключить библиотеку `algorithm`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;
  cout << "List size: ";
  cin >> n;
  vector <string> a(n);
  for (int i = 0; i != n; i++) {
    string FIO;
    cin >> FIO;
    a[i] = FIO;
  }
  sort(a.begin(), a.end());
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout<<a[i]<<'\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```